# TypeError: someobject.somefunction(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular-promise

I have created a utility function for getting the total size of the webtable using protractor and javascript.

```
this.getTableSize = function(tableElement, rowSelector, columnSelector){

        return {

            row: tableElement.all(rowSelector).count(),
            column : tableElement.all(columnSelector).count()
        }

    };
```

However on using the same function , i am geeting the error:

```
tableActions.getTableSize(table,by.css("tr"),by.css("th")).then(function(obj){
          console.log(obj);
      })
```

The error which i am getting is :

```
 TypeError: tableActions.getTableSize(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: Why do you call `then` on the result? It doesn't return a promise.

Comment: because it doesnt return a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your method to handle the promises correctly.

I assume that tableElement.all(rowSelector).count() returns a promise else you will have to handle the callbacks;

```js
this.getTableSize = function (tableElement, rowSelector, columnSelector) {
  return Promise.all([tableElement.all(rowSelector).count(), tableElement.all(columnSelector).count()]).then(function(data) {
    return {
      row: data[0],
      column: data[1]
    }
  })
};

tableActions.getTableSize(table, by.css("tr"), by.css("th")).then(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
})
```

[Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) does not return the array of resolved data with [bluebird promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) so use.

```js
this.getTableSize = function (tableElement, rowSelector, columnSelector) {
  return ableElement.all(rowSelector).count().then(function(c) {
    return ableElement.all(columnSelector).count().then(function (c2) {
      return {
        row: c,
        column: c2
      } 
    })
  })
};

tableActions.getTableSize(table, by.css("tr"), by.css("th")).then(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
})
```

Comment: Hi, yes tableElement.all(rowSelector).count() returns a promise. I ran the below code as ```this.getTableSize = function (tableElement, rowSelector, columnSelector) {
    return Promise.all(tableElement.all(rowSelector).count(), tableElement.all(columnSelector).count()).
    then(function(data) {
      return {
        row: data[0],
        column: data[1]
      }
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
     console.log(reason);
    })
  };```. And now its giving error as:TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable and also obj comes out to be undefined

Comment: are you using bluebird promise or native?@ashishchauhan

Comment: @ashishchauhan use another snippet if yes.

Comment: my bad it must be an array of promises, updated the code for first snippet @ashishchauhan

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot its working now with the another snippet. Could you please help me understand what was the issue? Also, could you please send me a good link (if possible) where i can learn more about promised. Much appreciated help anyways:)

Comment: first try to understand how the asynchronous calls are handled in javascript(event loop) and how to handle them in your code. for reading about the promises there are a lot of options to start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because you are using `.then()` on a function that does not return a `promise`.

Here's an example of a working `promise`:

```
let promise1 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let dataReceivedSuccessfully = false; 

    if (dataReceivedSuccessfully) {
        resolve('Data Available!'); 
    }
    if (!dataReceivedSuccessfully) {
        reject('Data Corrupted!'); 
    }
}) 

promise1.then( (success) => {
    console.log(success); 
}).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

You can use this in your code to return a `resolve` or `reject`, and then you will be able to use `.then()`.

> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/promises-in-javascript-explained-277b98850de

Comment: Thanks for the help:)